# Cargar Selected Option con los resultados obtenidos desde la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select

Tengo una tabla con todos mis registros de la base de datos, cuando doy en la opcion "EDITAR" me abre un formulario con la informacion ya cargada dependiendo del id del registro que se eligio, pero dentro de ese formulario hay listas desplegables y no logro hacer que me cargue la opcion que ya esta registrada en la base de datos.

Me carga toda la lista de options pero no me selecciona la opcion que ya esta registrada. he intentado con [selected] pero no me ha funcionado.

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="actividad.FK_LINEAMIENTO" (ngModelChange)="onDropdownChange($event)" class="form-control" name="lineamiento" id="lineamiento" required>
      <option *ngFor="let lineamiento of lineamientos" [ngValue]="lineamiento.PK_LINEAMIENTO" [selected]="lineamiento.PK_LINEAMIENTO === actividad.FK_LINEAMIENTO" class="form-control">{{lineamiento.NOMBRE}}</option>    
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

El atributo correcto es [value], no [ngValue]. Lo del selected no es necesario. Y creo que la clase form-control en options no es necesaria:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="actividad.FK_LINEAMIENTO (ngModelChange)="onDropdownChange($event)"
   class="form-control"
   name="lineamiento"
   id="lineamiento" required>
  <option *ngFor="let lineamiento of lineamientos" [value]="lineamiento.PK_LINEAMIENTO">
    {{lineamiento.NOMBRE}}
  </option>    
</select>
```